# Как из атрибута SRC картинки вытащить папки (папки) и изображение по отдельности?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть три изображения:

```
<img src="http://site.com/images/icons/arrow_icon.jpg">
<img src="images/icons/arrow_icon.jpg">
<img src="icons/arrow_icon.jpg">
```

Как в этих случаях через регулярное выражение получить список папок и отдельно изображение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_file_info($file){
    $fileinfo = parse_url($file);
    $fileinfo = pathinfo($fileinfo['path']);
    return array(
        'file_name' => $fileinfo['basename'],
        'file_path' => trim($fileinfo['dirname'],'/'),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getPath = (url) => {
  try {
    return new URL(url).pathname;
  } catch (e) {
    return url;
  }
};
let result = [...document.querySelectorAll('img')].map(el => {
  let url = getPath(el.getAttribute('src'));
  return {
    path: url.match(/([^/]+(?=\/))|^[^/.]+$/g) || [],
    file: url.replace(/.*?([^/]+\.[a-z]+)?$/, '$1'),
  };
});

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, '   ');
```

```html
<img src="http://site.com/images/icons/arrow_icon.jpg">
<img src="images/icons/arrow_icon.jpg">
<img src="icons/arrow_icon.jpg">
<img src="images/icons">
<img src="icons/">
<img src="arrow_icon.jpg">
<pre></pre>
```

P.S. как-то проглядел тег `php`. Смотрите в сторону [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php). Там еще проще, чем с JS